# Why does WebClient.OpenRead time out on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, tcp, windows-server-2008-r2

I have the following c# code:

```
static string TestWebClient(string url)
{
    var urlFormatted = string.Format(url, List, UserName, AdminPw);
    var returnValue = "URL:" + urlFormatted + Environment.NewLine;
    try
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Proxy = null;
            using (var data = client.OpenRead(urlFormatted))
            {
                if (data != null)
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
                    {
                        var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        returnValue += responseFromServer.Contains("1 members total")
                            ? "User is a member"
                            : "User is not a member.";
                        returnValue += Environment.NewLine;
                        returnValue += responseFromServer;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    returnValue += "Null data returned from OpenRead";
                }

            }
        }
        return returnValue;

    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        if (wex.Message.Contains("(404) Not Found"))
        {
            returnValue =
                string.Format("TestWebRequest: Page for group not found url : {0}" + Environment.NewLine + " WebException : {1}", urlFormatted, wex.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            returnValue = string.Format("TestWebRequest WebException: url : {0}" + Environment.NewLine + " Message : {1}", urlFormatted, wex.Message);
            if (wex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                returnValue += string.Format(Environment.NewLine + "TestWebRequest: ProtocolError Status Code : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)wex.Response).StatusCode);
                returnValue += string.Format(Environment.NewLine + "TestWebRequest: ProtocolError Status Description : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)wex.Response).StatusDescription);
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return string.Format("TestWebRequest: Error sending request url : {0}" + Environment.NewLine + " Exception : {1}", urlFormatted, ex);
    }
}
```

When the method `Webclient.OpenRead()` tries to access the URL I need (via the call to `client.OpenRead(urlFormatted)`) it times out every time when running from Windows Server 2008 R2.

If I run this code via a console application, I get the following message and stack trace:

```
Message : The operation has timed out
Stacktrace :    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
   at TestWebRequest.Program.TestWebClientDownloadString(String url)
```

If I call the method as part of an asp.net web service I get the following:

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

The strange thing is that it *only* times out when running on our Windows Server 2008 R2 instance. It works as expected from my local device (a Windows 7 machine), a windows server 2012 instance and a windows server 2003 instance.

I have tried passing in other URLs, and the only URL that causes the time out is the one I need. I'm guessing that something is going on with the communication between my application running on Windows Server 2008 R2 and the server hosing the resource I need. I say my application because I am able to access the URL via web browsers without difficulty from whatever machine I'm on.

I am using asp.net 4.0 and c#.

Comment: Pause the debugger during the hand, post the complete stack.

Comment: Actually I misread the question. This times out as you write. How did you make sure that the URL is OK?

Comment: I am able to access the resource using the URL via web browser on all of the machines I've tried. I am able to access it via my application except when my application is running on Windows Server 2008 R2. I have attempted to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am one of the systems people that works with Marc so I was able to run Wireshark and determined the TLS key exchange was not completing.  The TLS protocol just stopped. I found very little applicable info on this issue. I compared working windows servers not running 2008r2 with 2008r2 using Nartac IIS Crypto and the setting were identical. I decided to try adding a registry key to disable TLSv1.0 for the client which is not present by default. Adding this key resolved the problem.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000